# Connect two app services and easy tables in the azure protal

Tags: c#, api, azure, azure-mobile-services, portal

I would like to connect two mobile app services and their easy tables in the azure portal.
The two system have users with different read and edit rights.
The first system is read only users and the other system is admin users.

So when one user post something to a table in the first app service, it should trigger a post or event in the second app service.

The two app-services endpoints may look like this:

https:// some-random-url .azurewebsites.net/tables/posts

https:// some-other-random-url .azurewebsites.net/tables/posts

Is there some way to connect two azure mobile app services via an Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy tables, you are using the Node.js backend for your mobile app. You could leverage KUDU or App Service Editor to check your backend code, details you could follow [Understanding the Azure App Service Editor](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36467.understanding-the-azure-app-service-editor.aspx).

> So when one user post something to a table in the first app service, it should trigger a post or event in the second app service.

Per my understanding, azure mobile apps provide a easy way to expose your table APIs. You may internally call your second mobile app endpoint within your first mobile app with the relevant authentication. Moreover, I would recommend you follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/) for a better understanding of Azure Mobile Apps.

Additionally, you could provide more detailed scenario for your issue, then we could provide other better solution for you to implement your requirement.

Comment: I understand, I will do that in the future. This information gave me just what i needed and I solved the problem!